# Erlang gen_server cast bad return value

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I try to cast message to a gen_server:

```
 gen_server:cast({global, ID}, {watchers}).
```

The handler is:

```
handle_cast({watchers}, State) ->
    case State#table_state.watchers of
    [] ->
        {reply, no_watchers, State};
    _ ->
        {reply, State#table_state.watchers, State}
    end;
```

But when I execute `gen_server:cast` the gen_server terminates with error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Apr-2011::18:26:07 ===
** Generic server 1 terminating 
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',{watchers}}
** When Server state == {table_state,1,"1",11,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {bad_return_value,{reply, no_watchers, {table_state,3,"3",11,[]}}}
```

Why do I get `bad_return_value`?

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to send `{watchers}` (an atom inside a tuple), it's enough to send just the `watchers` atom alone as a message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot reply using cast (see [`gen_server` documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_cast-2)). That is the whole point of casting an asynchronous message instead of using call.

In your case you want to return a reply, so use `gen_server:call/2` instead.

Comment: So `handle_cast` should return `{noreply,State}`. Use `gen_server:call` and `handle_call` for a synchronous call which returns a value.